# If $f,g$ satisfy Rolle's condition, then there exists $c$ such that $f'(c)+f(c)g'(c)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f,g$ be functions that satisfy condition of Rolle's theorem on segment $(a,b).$ Show that, if $f(x)>0$, then there exists point $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)+f(c)g'(c)=0.$

I tried to use that the function $fg$ also satisfies Rolle's theorem but that did not give me what I want. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: look at
$$
h(x) = \ln(f(x)) + g(x).
$$

Comment: Rolle only requires that $f(a) = f(b)$, which I assume to be both greater than $0$.

Comment: Note that if you use $h(x) := f(x) e^{g(x)}$ instead, then as far as I can tell you don't even need the assumption that $f(x) > 0$.